# How can I call an xaml file from a folder in app shell?

Tags: shell, xamarin.forms, tabbar, getfiles, app-shell

I have a folder named *jsonarray* containing *Page3.xaml* . I want to show this page calling it from AppShell.xaml. The ordinary method calling in AppShell.xaml is:

```
<TabBar>
<ShellContent Title="About" Icon="icon_about.png" Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
</TabBar>
```

I tried:

```
<TabBar>
<ShellContent Title="Page3" Icon="Page3.png" Route="Page3" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page3}" />
</TabBar>
```

**but it errors: " Cannot resolve type "Page3".**

Any idea how do I call the *Page3* from the *jsonarray* folder?

Comment: Check `local:` namespace on the top of xaml. Since you've created a different folder, it is supposed to be a different namespace name. Like `local2:<Same with the AboutPage here>/jsonarray`

Comment: Yes it has a different namespace. e.x (AboutPage) : namespace just4json.Views
(Page3): namespace just4json.jsonarray
How should I do it?

Comment: If your "local" deffined like this `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:just4json.Views"` , then add a line: `xmlns:local2="clr-namespace:just4json.jsonarray"` and use "local2" in ContentTemplate